# How to read txt files in gnuplot

Tags: matlab, gnuplot

In my cpp code I save data into a txt file in the following way:

```
val={1,2.03,3.88,4,5}
for (i=0; i<4; i++)
{
            myfile2 << val << " ";
}
```

So at the end I get a file that looks like:
1 2.03 3.88 4 5

I read it in Matlab easily with one line and I can plot it without specifying an "x axis label"

How can I read this file in for plotting in gnuplot?

Is there a convention way to save txt files that can be easily read in gnuplot and Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://lowrank.net/gnuplot/datafile-e.html it looks like you need to write both the x and y values into a gnuplot file.

If your C++ code looked something like ...

```
val={1,2.03,3.88,4,5}
for (i=0; i<4; i++)
{
            myfile2 << i << " " << val << std::endl;
}
```

Then you should have it in a format acceptable for both MATLAB and GNU plot.